# Adding characters to each line in a QString

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QString with a multi-line text without space at the begining like:

```
Lorem ispum   
Dolor a si met   
Hulu il it er
```

and I would like to add space to each line to obtain something like this:

```
      Lorem ispum  
      Dolor a si met   
      Hulu il it er
```

For information, I use QString of QT

Comment: Will all lines be in a single string, or one string per line?

Comment: every line in a single string (separated by \n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `QString::replace()` :

```
QString s = "Lorem ispum\nDolor a si met\nHulu il it er ";
s.replace(QRegExp("^"), "\t");
```

You could also do it without regular expression :

```
s.insert(0, '\t');
s.replace('\n', "\n\t");
```

This would add one tab (`\t`) at the beginning of each line, if you want to add spaces, just replace `\t` with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over every character in the string, while copying to a second string. As soon as you see a newline then copy that and add the spaces needed.

Or simply use the [`replace`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace-10) function:

```
str.replace('\n', "\n\t");
```